# jQuery not being found by icheck using webpack (Angular 2)

Tags: jquery, node.js, angular, webpack, icheck

I am writing an app using Angular 2, webpack and I am using the icheck front-end library (http://icheck.fronteed.com/) which requires jQuery.

I am requiring them in my component thusly:

```
var jQuery: any = require("jquery");
require('../../../js/jquery.icheck.min.js');
require('../../../css/checkbox/orange.css');
```

This build successfully using the webpack server and npm, but I get an error in the browser:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined (jquery.min.icheck.js:11)
```

I have used this plugin before in an Angular 2 component but I never had any problems like this. I have compared the current app with the working app and I can't see any differences; it should work!

I am really up against it now and have to get this prepared for Monday. Anyone have any problems like this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to Remove

```
var jQuery: any = require("jquery");
```

Add those code in header of the ts file.

```
declare var jQuery;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'foo'
})

export class FooBarComponent {
    $: any = $;
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        // use this way
        this.$(".fooBar") ...
    }
}
```